# Automatically Download Data in R from Website where click is required

Tags: r

First time question here! I'm new to R and am trying to have some fun in it with some NBA data. I want to automatically download shot tracking data and put get it into R so I can produce images, run analysis, etc.

I have been unable to find a website that displays all of the necessary data that I could just grab through web scraping so I turned my attention to finding files that have all of the data.

I found a website that has exactly the data I am looking for, but to download it I have to click a download button. In the upper right corner of the chart at the below link there is a "download csv" link that gives me all of the data related to every shot taken in the NBA. Can anyone please help me to figure out how I can automatically get this with R instead of going and manually downloading it each day?

Below is the link.

http://nbasavant.com/shot_search.php?hfST=&hfQ=&hfSZB=&hfSZA=&hfSZR=&ddlYear=2017&txtGameDateGT=&txtGameDateLT=&ddlGameTimeGT_min=&ddlGameTimeGT_sec=&ddlGameTimeLT_min=&ddlGameTimeLT_sec=&ddlShotDistanceGT=&ddlShotDistanceLT=&ddlTeamShooting=&ddlTeamDefense=&hfPT=&ddlGroupBy=player&ddlOrderBy=shots_made_desc&hfGT=0%7C&ddlShotMade=&ddlMin=0#results

Comment: So do you just want to be able to download all of the shot data from a single day in R? Or do you want to download it from a longer period of time?

Comment: The `robots.txt` for the site prohibits automated downloads. Bypassing means choosing an unethical path and — soon — a potentially legally ugly one as well. Noting this for others since most questioners don't have an issue with choosing data over ethics.

Comment: @DavidRosenman. The link Is actually all of the shot data for the entire season up until this point. So If I can automatically download it each day it will be the most up to date.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks for pointing that out. How were you able to identify that? I wasn't aware that would be an issue since it is a free download. This isn't the only site that i am running into this sort of issue, so I'd really just like to understand the concept of how to automate it when I run into this and it isn't illegal. If you know how to do this, but would like to share how on a legal example I would really appreciate it.

Comment: http://nbasavant.com/robots.txt

Comment: You can use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robotstxt/index.html or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spiderbar/index.html to automagically find, read and not violate